# How do you include the path variable in a GET Request for JUnit Test?

Tags: junit, spring-boot-test, mockmvc

I am trying to test the following method but am getting a

> ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter.

My `controller` is the following:

```
@GetMapping("/get/{id}")
    public User getUserById(@PathVariable int id) {
        return userService.getUserById(id);
    }
```

And my test is the following:

```
    @Test
    void getUserById(Integer id) throws Exception {
        User user1 = new User(1, "FirstName", "LastName", "Address", 
        "1234566", "email@gmail.com");
        when(userService.getUserById(1)).thenReturn(user1);
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/get/{id}", "1"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
             assertEquals(userController.getUserById(1), user1);
    }
```

How do I resolve this exception to make the test pass?

Answer (score 0):

Write your mockMVC like that.

```
val response = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/get/1"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
```

and assert with response like...

```
response.andExpect(jsonPath("$.your.object.path", is("your_expected_output")));
```